# How to search a test name in NUnit GUI

Tags: nunit

I have written many tests and when i opened NUnit try to run some test it is taking time for me to find the testname where it is displaying in NUNit GUI.
Is there an option like Ctrl+F in NUnit to find the test?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option like that (yet) in either of the NUnit GUI applications.

When asking questions, it's a good idea to be very specific about what you are using. Of course, if you have only seen one "NUnit GUI", you might assume that there are no others. But it's still helpful to give the name of the command you execute and the version of the software (at a minimum) in case it turns out that there are more applications than you are aware of.

In this case, the answer would be the same for both the NUnit Version 2 GUI "nunit.exe" and the TestCentric GUI (currently version 1.2) which runs NUnit tests. There is a plan for the TestCentric GUI to eventually support such a search. The V2 GUI is legacy software and isn't developed actively any longer.